# Overriding Bootstrap variables vs overriding classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

What's the benefit of overriding Bootstrap SCSS variables vs just overriding Bootstrap's CSS class rules?

For example,

Overriding variables:

```
$custom-font-size: $input-font-size;
```

Overriding class:

```
.someClass {
   font-size: $input-font-size;
}
```

Comment: Overriding variables is global which is much more powerful and quicker than trying to change variables per scss template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, duplication of output. If you override classes then that will mean that in your CSS you'll be including both the Bootstrap definition and the overriding definition. Not ideal, so on a smaller scale this works fine.

But on the bigger scale though, overriding potentially hundreds of classes (if not more) will be both a waste of resources for any end users (since there will be more data to download) but also a waste of time because you have to go and find every single instance where you want to override the use of that variable. Changing just the variable once will change every instance of where that variable is used, *and* you don't get the extra output. A win-win.